# ui:msg with Dictionary in GWT

Tags: gwt, dictionary, internationalization, uibinder, msg

Is it possible to use ui:msg with a Dictionary or a custom HashMap in GWT?
If so how?

Thanks
A

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if that is possible, but what you can do is using POJO's.

like:

```
<ui:with type="org.mypackage.MyMessages"
    field="messages" />
<g:Label text="{messages.hello}" />
```

Where MyMessages is a class containing a method getHello() which returns a string. So you will be wrapping the dictionary inside the class MyMessages

Comment: Exellent! Thanks for the reply. Will see if i can get it working with a map like so: <g:label text="messages.get('key')" /> then you wouldnt have to have a method for every message but only a map with keys and texts.

Comment: Btw how do I format the code in posts like you have here at stackoverflow?

Comment: You have a button for that, just select you code and press the '101010' button